# How to know what commands are executed on a directory in Centos?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, centos6

I have three directories(farmio,farmio-table,farmio-table-throttle) in apps directory of AWS-Centos server under username ec2-user, every time I do a ls -la I see two folders(farmio-table,farmio-table-throttle) accessed frequently and  the pid file stored inside the folder are wiped out for which my java programs doesn't execute properly.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-94-221-19 apps]$ ls -la
total 49036
drwxrwxr-x 5 ec2-user root         4096 Nov  7 09:39 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user root         4096 May 29 12:20 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user       29 Nov  6 06:26 date.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user     4096 Nov  6 06:42 farmio
drwxrwxrwx 7 ec2-user ec2-user     4096 Nov  7  2015 farmio-table
-rw-r----- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 25090806 Nov  7 09:43 farmio-table-bin.zip
drwxrwxrwx 7 ec2-user ec2-user     4096 Nov  7  2015 farmio-table-throttle
-rw-r----- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 25092514 Nov  7 09:39 farmio-table-throttle-bin.zip
```

Every time I try to check the folders are changed or replaced after five minutes.

Is there any way I could know which user and which command is executed in this directory so that its files are replaced/modified in Centos.

Answer (score 1):

Use command history to check all the previously run commands.

```
$ history
```

Comment: History only allows the commands that are directly entered from the terminal,
What if a Cron Job or external request like ssh is running , how to check that.